# crawling data website and save it to another database with laravel

Tags: php, laravel, web-crawler

I want crawl some data in website and save it to another database website with laravel
first  make a Helper and put simple_html_dom.php on it and call in composer.json

after that make a command(hospitalCrawler) and write code bellow

```
public function handle()
{
     $dom = \voku\helper\HtmlDomParser::file_get_html('link of website');
    $elements = $dom->find('.hospitalDetails a section');
    $hospitals = array();
    foreach ($elements as $key => $value){
        $hospital['title'] = $value->innerText();
        $hospitals[] = $hospital;
    }
    foreach ($hospitals as $key => $value){
        $p = new Page($value);
        $p->save();

    }
}
```

and data successfully save it in my database
but I have 2 problem

the first problem :my div have three element (title-address-state)

```
<div class="hospitalDetails">
<section>
    <a>
        <h2>title</h2>
        <p>state</p>
        <span>address</span>
    </a>
```

but I can only save title in database and can't access to address and state
second problem: is about pagination
I can save first of the page and other page doesn't save in database

please give me a solution:)
thanks:)

Comment: If you do a `dd($elements);` after where the elements are fetched, what does that show? ... also, based on the html example, it seems that find order should be: `.hospitalDetails section a`?

Comment: I get all of content in .hospitalDetails

Comment: how can get separately h2 - span - p